# Knockout - Access to element by index on observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a view with a foreach, I need to create a computed field that concatenates two fields but these two fields are inside an observable array, I know I can refer to my item in this way: myArray()[0].firstName + myArray()[0].lastName but because I'm in a foreach, I need to know the index:

Let's say this is my computed field:

```
fullName: ko.computed(function(idx) {
     return myArray()[idx].firstName + ' ' + myArray()[idx].lastName;
})
```

If my previous code is possible, how can I get the index in my knockout foreach to send it to this computed field and get the fullName?

Now I have another issue,

```
employeeList: ko.observableArray(),

employeeFullName: ko.computed(function(idx) {
   return employeeList()[idx].firstName + ' ' + employeeList()[idx].lastName;
})
```

The problem is that I have an error on the page that says employeeList is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your `employeeFullName` computed observable needs to be a function instead:

```
employeeFullName: function(idx) {
     return this.employeeList()[idx].firstName + ' ' + this.employeeList()[idx].lastName;
}
```

If `employeeFullName` and `employeeList` are both in the same viewmodel then you can access `employeeFullName` through the `$parent` context. In addition you would pass the current index using `$index`. For instance, here is a simple list with the binding:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: employeeList">
    <li data-bind="html: $parent.employeeFullName($index())"></li>
</ul>
```

Notice the `()` after `$index`; this is important.